# Pyspark actions on dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I say `dataframe.show()` in pyspark. Am I performing a transformation/action? I want to especially know what is better to perform after persisting the dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean better? Better among what?

Comment: So there are multiple transformations I want to perform later on. So I thought I would place persists at some steps so that I could save time. To my understanding, I have to call an action after persisting. So wanted to know if show was an action and it would suffice after I persist my dataframe.

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you. It's what I was looking for.

Comment: Be generous & upvote the linked answer